# Azure Apple Push Notification Error: 400 Bad Request

Tags: azure, push-notification

Azure Apple Push Notification is giving me the following error. This was working as of a couple of weeks ago. I thought it might be my application, but I used the default template used in Azure "Test Send" and got the same thing. Anyone else experiencing this?

"Failed to send test message. Error:

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Bad Request\",\"code\":\"BadRequest\"}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","code":"BadRequest"}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This was working as of a couple of weeks ago. I thought it might be my application, but I used the default template used in Azure "Test Send" and got the same thing. Anyone else experiencing this?

According to your description, I assume that it may be caused by the validation of your certificate. I recommend you createing a new Apple Push Notification Client SSL Certificate, more details you could refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW6).

About how to Configure and run the iOS project, please refer to the Azure official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#configure-and-run-the-ios-project-optional).

Comment: That was it, I really should have checked that. Thanks!